# Re-Usable fetch function with query string

Tags: reactjs

I have a fetch function inside of my react component, which I wish to "outsourse" in a separate component.

```
export const fetchBooksBySubject = (selectedValue) => {
const options = {
  method: `GET`,
};
fetch(`${server}/books?subjects_like=${selectedValue}`, options)
.then((response) => {
  if(response.ok){
    return response.json()
  }
    throw new Error('Api is not available') 
  })
.catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching data: ', error)
 })
}
```

Basically selectedValue is a prop coming from a child of App.jsx. As soon as the value is selected in a component, fetch should fire with this value in a query string. I tried to export the function above as a component and use it in App.jsx

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchBooksBySubject(selectedValue).then(data => setBookList(data));
  }, [selectedValue])

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSelectedValue(e);
    fetchBooksBySubject(selectedValue);
  };
```

But this throws Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: Try let data = fetchBooksBySubject(selectedValue); setBookList(data);

Comment: data is undefined, fetch is done right

Answer (score 0):

Here's a custom hook you can use with fast and reusable data fetching, a built-in cache, and other features like polling intervals and revalidation.

Hook:

```
const useBooks = (selectedValue) =>
{
      const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())

      const { data, error } = useSWR(`/api/books?subjects_like=${selectedValue}`, fetcher)

      return {
          books: data,
          isLoading: !error && !data,
          isError: error
      }
}
```

Usage:

```
const { books, isLoading, isError } = useBooks(selectedValue)

if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>
else return <div>Your content here</div>
```

[swr docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started)

Without `swr`:

```
useEffect(() =>
{
    const fetchData = async (selectedValue) =>
    {
        const books = await fetchBookBySubject(selectedValue)
        setBookList(books)
    }
      
    fetchData(selectedValue)
}, [selectedValue, bookList])
```

Comment: is there no way to do this without? swr is way too advanced, I  am looking for a reason, why my code i no working and how to imrove it. Thanks!

Comment: @KatharinaSchreiber I added a section on using a simple effect to do this, although it has none of the reusability or cache features of `swr`. Using `async` and `await` instead of `then` may be better for you.

Comment: Booklist is still undefined, but the request goes to API

Comment: @KatharinaSchreiber The request is going to the API, but are you sure anything is being returned?

Comment: In a console network section - yes. Also in a fetch file, but not in the app.js. There it is still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was, that I wasn't returning my fetch. I am a beginner, so my understanding is, that my App.js just couldn't access the data from fetchBooksBySubject withot this return

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const server = dev ? 'http://localhost:3001' : 'https://your_deployment.server.com';
// later definable for developement, test, production

export const FetchBooksBySubject = (selectedValue) => {
    const options = {
      method: `GET`,
    };
    return fetch(`${server}/books?subjects_like=${selectedValue}`, options)
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.ok){
        return response.json()
      }
        throw new Error('Api is not available') 
      })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching data: ', error)
    })
}
```

Same as here:

```
let sum = (a,b) => {a+b}
sum(1,2) //undefined

let sum1 = (a,b) => {return a+b}
sum1(1,2) //3
```